# Proving that $\sqrt{4ab-1}=m^2$ is equivalent to $a=b$. where $a$ and $b$ are non zero integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

So the original question was to prove that if $4ab-1$ divides $4a^2-1)^2$, then $a=b$ where $a$ and $b$ are non zero integers. (IMO 2007)

I proceed this way:

$(4a²-1)²/(4ab-1)=q$ where $q$ is natural number.

So therefore: $4a^2-1=q\sqrt{4ab-1}$ so $\sqrt{{}4ab-1}$ must be integer for that to hold so:  $4ab-1=m^2$ but now I have to prove that for the latter to hold $a$ must equal $b$.

Does anyone know how to do?

Comment: If $\sqrt{ab-1}$ is an integer, how do you conclude it is in fact a square? Also, $\sqrt{4ab-1}$ fails to be an integer even *if* we have $a=b$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So the problem is false? And I meant 4ab-1=m² not the square root

Comment: At least it does not follow from $(4ab-1)\mid (4a^2-1)^2$ that $\sqrt{ab-1}$ is an integer. Check with $a=b=1$: $3\mid 9$ but $\sqrt{8}\notin\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Test $a=b=4$ $\sqrt{4.4.4-1}$ is not integer.... :/

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=894656%23p894656&sid=53ce592bbf78c210d3ccc0a951588028

Comment: Your start is wrong (you did not take the square root of $q$), so it is impossible to finish your proof. Therefore, I will vote to close. If you edit your question, I will of course vote to reopen.